# Some gamma function questions...

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, gamma-function

I have shown that $\Gamma(a+1)=a\Gamma(a)$ for all $a>0$.

But I'd also like to show the following 2 things:

1) Using the previous fact, I'd like to show that $\lim_{a \to 0^{+}}a\Gamma(a) = \Gamma(1)=1$

The second equality is obvious, but how about the limit equality?

2) Using 1) then, I'd like to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} {{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}\over{x}}$. The suggestion is to, using the first two facts above, calculate

$$\lim_{a \to 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a}{{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}\over{x}}$$.

I can sort of prove 1), provided I am allowed to switch the $a$ limit and the $M$ limit outside the integral (we replace the upper limit $\infty$ with $M$ and take the limit as $M \to \infty$ using the MCT.) However, though I get the correct answer of $1$, it seems fishy that I am allowed to switch the limits like this.

Number 2) I have no idea.

Comment: 1) Show that $\Gamma$ is continuous in $1$. 2), write the second integral as a combination of $\Gamma$ values.

Comment: I'm having trouble showing gamma is even continuous. I've seen similar questions on here, but none of them have been fully answered.

Comment: Which definition/representation of $\Gamma$ are you working with? $$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}\,dx$$ for $\operatorname{Re} z > 0$ (or $z > 0$ if only real arguments are considered)? If so, Riemann integral or Lebesgue integral?

Comment: real arguments, and the integral is not specified.

Comment: The use Lebesgue. The continuity follows from the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Yes, but what function dominates the integrand? And how do we even know that $\Gamma$ is measurable?

Comment: That the integrand is continuous on $(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$ is fairly easy to see. Then you need to look at a function $g(x)$ such that $$x^{z-1}e^{-x}\leqslant g(x)$$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$ and all $z \in [a,b]$, where $0 < a < b < \infty$ are arbitrarily chosen so that the point $z_0$ at which you want to show the continuity of $\gamma$ lies in $(a,b)$. Look a little at how the integrand depends on $z$ to find the dominating function.

Comment: If we can choose $a,b$ arbitrary, then the function is dominated by  $\max{x^b,1}$.

Comment: Is that integrable?

Comment: Nope, and it isn't correct either. I have no idea what the function is.

Comment: Since the integrand has a factor $e^{-x}$, you can hope to find a dominating function with the same factor. So you need something dominating $x^{z-1}$ for all $z\in [a,b]$ such that when you multiply that with $e^{-x}$, the result is integrable.

Comment: $x^{b-1}$ I think dominates that, but not sure how to show the result is integrable.

Comment: For $x < 1$, you have $x^{a-1} > x^{b-1}$ when $a < b$.

Comment: well, then $x^{a-1}$ dominates there, so we have a piecewise result. But again, how do we know this is integrable? That's essentially asking, is the gamma function integrand integrable?

Comment: Good, you see that it boils down to the integrability of $x^{z-1}e^{-x}$. Since the integrand is continuous, you need only be concerned with the behaviour at the ends of the domain of integration. At $0$, the integrand may be unbounded, and you need to see that it doesn't grow too fast. Using $e^{-x} \leqslant 1$ suffices to see that $\int_0^1 x^{z-1}e^{-x}\,dx < \infty$. At the other end, you must see that the integrand decays fast enough to have a finite integral. The $x^{z-1}$ term grows at most like a polynomial. Can you use that to reach the conclusion?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not seeing it. If I knew each of these were integrable, I would be able to simply switch the limits as in the original method I came up with. It also seems to depend heavily on $z$.

Comment: For what $\alpha$ is $\int_0^1 x^\alpha\,dx$ finite? For what $\beta$ is $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\beta}$ finite? Can you bound $x^{z-1}e^{-x}$ by an $x^\alpha$ with a finite integral on $(0,1]$ and by an $\frac{1}{x^\beta}$ with a finite integral on $[1,\infty)$?

Comment: For the first one, all $\alpha > -1$, for the second, all $\beta > 0$. Since $e^{-x}$ is decreasing from $1$, doesn't it suffice to bound only $x^{z-1}$?

Comment: Not $\beta > 0$. You need the decay of $e^{-x}$ as $x\to\infty$ for the integrability.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\beta >1$

Comment: Okay. So can you, for an arbitrary $z > 0$, show that there is a constant $K$ (depending on $z$) with $$x^{z-1}e^{-x} \leqslant \frac{K}{x^\beta}$$ on $[1,\infty)$ for some $\beta > 1$?

Comment: No I can't. Perhaps if I saw it it would be obvious, but the fact that $z$ is borderline arbitrary makes it hard for me to see

Comment: We aren't given the taylor series, nor have we learned anything about the gamma function. This is just a practice qualifying question.

Comment: Let $n > z$. Then look at the power series: $$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \dotsc + \frac{x^n}{n!} + \dotsc$$ Therefore $\frac{x^{z-1}}{e^x} <$ ?

Comment: n!, where n depends on z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to part (2) using the Gamma function and the result of part (1):

$$\int_0^\infty x^a \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{x}dx  = \int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-x}dx-\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-3x}dx.$$

For the second integral on the RHS, make the change of variables $u = 3x$ to obtain

$$\int_0^\infty x^a \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{x}dx  = \int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-x}dx-3^{-a}\int_0^\infty u^{a-1}e^{-u}dx.$$

Using the definition of the Gamma function,

$$\int_0^\infty x^a \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{x}dx  = (1-3^{-a})\Gamma(a) = \frac{1-3^{-a}}{a}a\Gamma(a).$$

From part (1) we have $\lim_{a \rightarrow 0+} a\Gamma(a) = 1$, and using L'Hospital's rule we know that

$$\lim_{a \rightarrow 0+}\frac{1-3^{-a}}{a} = \log(3)$$

Therefore

$$\lim_{a \rightarrow 0+}\int_0^\infty x^a \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{x}dx  =  \lim_{a \rightarrow 0+}\frac{1-3^{-a}}{a} \lim_{a \rightarrow 0+} a\Gamma(a) = \log(3).$$

Answer (score 3):

1. Since $\Gamma(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$, we get $$\lim_{a\to0^+}a\Gamma(a)=\lim_{a\to0^+}\Gamma(a+1)=\Gamma(1)=1$$
2. Here is how I usually approach this type of integral, but it does not use the Gamma function, just the fact that for $x\gt0$, $-1\le\frac{e^{-x\vphantom{\Large1}}-1}{x}\le0$:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
   &=\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
   &=\lim_{a\to0}\left(\int_a^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_a^\infty\frac{e^{-3x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
   &=\lim_{a\to0}\left(\int_a^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{3a}^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
   &=\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^{3a}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
   &=\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^{3a}\frac1{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^{3a}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[8pt]
   &=\log(3)
   \end{align}
   $$

Answer (score 0):

The limit follows from the functional property of the Gamma function:
$$
       a\Gamma(a)=\Gamma(a+1).
$$